# SetAttribute for value isnt working correctly

Tags: c#

I've been trying to get `SetAttribute` with the `webBrowser.Document` for a while, and for some reason the `webBrowser` fields don't get filled in.

I'm certain that I have the ID's correct, but perhaps i'm just overlooking something. I am setting textfields for the [netflix login website](https://www.netflix.com/Login).

My code is as follows:

```
var emailField = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("email");
var passField = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password");
emailField.SetAttribute("value", username);
passField.SetAttribute("value", password);
```

Thanks for any help, the username is a string which includes the email, and password contains the password, also in a string.

Comment: did u debug? if yes, what is the value of emailField and passField? do u see these values being filled up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your code in **DocumentCompleted**.

**Example**

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var emailField = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("email");
    var passField = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password");
    emailField.SetAttribute("value", "123");
    passField.SetAttribute("value", "456");
}
```

Try it again.